# Why is my sqlite3 query returning empty rows?

Tags: python, sqlite

I know I have to be making a dumb mistake here...

```
            checksum = self.hashItem(os.path.join(root, filename))
            print checksum
            query = 'SELECT * FROM tracked_file WHERE md5 = ?'
            self.con.execute(query, [str(checksum)])
            results = self.cur.fetchall()
            print results
```

Here's the table structure

```
'CREATE TABLE if not exists tracked_file (filename TEXT, filepath TEXT, date_created TEXT, date_modified TEXT, file_size INTEGER, sha1 TEXT, md5 TEXT, catalog_date TEXT, archive_date TEXT);'
```

and the output of the script is showing md5 values I can verify are in the table manually.

`48f3dd221a0cb5284c678b3aff24d668
[]
ff12917ca9ec1cf8bc913efdf7f3ade7
[]
7b5cf763ef1a75eceb0bb960421a3ec2
[]
390228bde6440ed38f45dbf8ea09d860
[]
c10e728e60e580b0eb97c3ab705b8fb9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the query against the connection:

```
self.con.execute(query, [str(checksum)])
```

But trying to get results from the cursor:

```
results = self.cur.fetchall()
```

The connection's `execute` method creates an intermediate cursor to run the SQL, but this won't be the same cursor you've created and stored in `self.cur`

Try:

```
self.cur.execute(query, [str(checksum)])
results = self.cur.fetchall()
```